# Laravel not changing language

Tags: laravel, translation

Laravel is not changing the language I have tried these methods in controller

```
if ($request->lang === 'English') {
            config(['app.locale' => 'en']);
        } else {
            config(['app.locale' => 'ar']);
        }
```

and this method

```
App::setLocale('ar')
```

Or this method

```
\App::setLocale('ar')
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have the language files under `resources/lang/ar` ?

Comment: @jrcamatog Yes it's under resources/lang/ar

Comment: Do note that the locale will only change for that specific request, not for the whole session.

Comment: @jrcamatog I want it for whole project all pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a middleware that puts the locale in the session and sets it.

```
php artisan make:middleware SetLocale
```

**app\Http\Middleware\SetLocale.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('lang') == 'English') {
            $request->session()->put('locale', 'en');
        } else {
            $request->session()->put('locale', 'ar');
        }

        App::setLocale($request->session()->get('locale'));

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then, add it to your global middleware (or to a middleware group).

**app\Http\Kernel.php**

```php
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    // other global middlewares
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
];
```